# RNN python numpy MemoryError

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

The purpose of this code is creating a recurrent neural network (RNN) to predict the future values of forex market movement.

The data set shape is (65524, 130) and the dtype is ‘object’.

Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"E:\Tutorial\FinalDF.csv", parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0], low_memory=False, dtype='unicode')
sequence_length = 500
n_features = len(df.columns)
val_ratio = 0.1
n_epochs = 3000
batch_size = 50

data = df.as_matrix()
data_processed = []
for index in range(len(data) - sequence_length):
    data_processed.append(data[index: index + sequence_length])
data_processed = np.array(data_processed)

val_split = round((1 - val_ratio) * data_processed.shape[0])
train = data_processed[:, int(val_split), :]
val = data_processed[int(val_split):, :]

print('Training data: {}'.format(train.shape))
print('Validation data: {}'.format(val.shape))



train_samples, train_nx, train_ny = train.shape
val_samples, val_nx, val_ny = val.shape

train = train.reshape((train_samples, train_nx * train_ny))
val = val.reshape((val_samples, val_nx * val_ny))

preprocessor = MinMaxScaler().fit(train)
train = preprocessor.transform(train)
val = preprocessor.transform(val)

train = train.reshape((train_samples, train_nx, train_ny))
val = val.reshape((val_samples, val_nx, val_ny))

X_train = train[:, : -1]
y_train = train[:, -1][:, -1]
X_val = val[:, : -1]
y_val = val[:, -1][:, -1]

X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], n_features))
X_val = np.reshape(X_val, (X_val.shape[0], X_val.shape[1], n_features))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:]), units=100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae', 'mse', 'accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=n_epochs,
    verbose=2)

preds_val = model.predict(X_val)
diff = []
for i in range(len(y_val)):
    pred = preds_val[i][0]
    diff.append(y_val[i] - pred)

real_min = preprocessor.data_min_[104]
real_max = preprocessor.data_max_[104]
print(preprocessor.data_min_[:1])
print(preprocessor.data_max_[:1])

preds_real = preds_val * (real_max - real_min) + real_min
y_val_real = y_val * (real_max - real_min) + real_min

plt.plot(preds_real, label='Predictions')
plt.plot(y_val_real, label='Actual values')
plt.xlabel('test')
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
print(model.summary())
```

Here is the error:

Using TensorFlow backend.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "E:/Tutorial/new.py", line 20, in

data_processed = np.array(data_processed)

MemoryError

Comment: Have you considered that maybe your dataset is just huge? You've got 65524 columns and 130 rows. That's 8518120 items. If every item was a single bit large, then your dataset would be just over a mb large... Factor in overhead and the fact that your data is bigger than one bit, and you've got a significant memory hog.

Comment: @JakobLovern thanks for answer, so you think [corei7 and 6 mb ram can not handle this]

Comment: Yeah, probably not. I'd suggest keeping most of the data on disk and grabbing for little bits at a time to edit on them.

Comment: also, you... only have 6 mb of ram? mb, right? like, not gb? What kind of dinosaur did you dig up that has so little ram?

Comment: @JakobLovern HAHAHA SORRY FOR THE MISTAKE, its 6 gb

Comment: I was a little worried, there. Anyways, what type of stuff are you storing in each cell?

Comment: @JakobLovern dinosaur

Comment: Do you still get the error when you try your code on a smaller dataset? If so, then it's a memory leak. If not, then you've simply got too large of a dataset and you should consider compartmentalizing it. Specifically, if this neural network works like a normal one, just pull data cell by cell from disk to train your AI. Though... You might need some serious low-level hackery to pull off a stunt like that.

Comment: @JakobLovern you were right it was about the dataset size. after using a smaller dataset i have another issue. i edit the post and add the new error

Comment: Ok, so that's a different problem from the memory error. For the sake of future people with questions, I'd like it if you would rollback your edits and phrase your question to focus on the memoryerror, then debug your code and post again as a new question. I'll post an answer to this question so it can get out of the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: this question was solved in comments through careful debugging.*

Memory errors, in my experience, come from one of three places:

- really freaking huge datasets
- Sho-bhlzim, dark eater of souls and left socks
- Memory leaks

All of these have a solution, if you don't mind getting your hands dirty.

### Memory Leaks

These are caused by a section of code that doesn't close properly. One example is fork bombs:

```
import os
while True:
  os.fork
```

The canonical example, to me, was in TI-Basic. Doing

```
:Lbl A
:If True
:Then
:Goto A
:End
```

Would open up a frame on the stack at the If statement, then go straight to the Lbl without closing it again via the End statement. <sub>yes, I know that's not quite accurate, but it's close enough.</sub>

Anyways, opening files and not closing them can also crash your stack. Lots of stuff can.

To Fix: Find it, kill it. Nothing else you can do. Also maybe some flow rewriting.

### Sho-bhlzim, eater of souls

You'll need a Buddhist monk, a catholic priest, four goats, a pentagram, a pentacle, six candles made of earwax, and six pages of the necronomicon. Doesn't matter which six. Good? Now read them and do whatever the mad visions say to do.

### Huge Datasets

These are actually pretty easy to test for. First, does your dataset LOOK huge? Is there a number on there that's bigger than 2^15? Yeah, you're probably best off here to begin with. Second, if you try a similar, but much smaller example dataset, does the error go away? Then you've got too big of a dataset.

Now, how do you fix this? Grab your trusty earwax candle and... Eww, why do you still have that? Throw it away! Ok, so you'll need to take the dataset and break it into a lot of little pieces. In the question, it was an AI that was being trained, so each (relatively small) piece of training data could be its own file. This kind of jigsawificstion can get pretty screwy, though, so you'll want to see if you can rewrite your code to use less memory first.

In the end, memory errors are caused by, unsurprisingly, not having enough memory. Optimizations that increase memory at the expense of speed are valuable in this endeavor.